# Python2: Recursion doesn't work when I put print statement in function but works otherwise

Tags: python, recursion

So I am doing minimum coin change problem recursively in python. I wanted to visualize how many recursive calls it's making. So I put a "print 'recursion'" in my function. But now it's continuously print recursion and not reaching output and program is not even stopping. Here is the program.

```
def min_coins(coins, change):
    print 'recursion' #program works without this line
    mincoins = change
    if change in coins:
        return 1
    else:
        for i in coins:
            if i<=change:
                numcoins = 1 + min_coins(coins, change-i)
                if(numcoins < mincoins):
                    mincoins = numcoins
    return mincoins

c = [1,5,25]
d = 50

print min_coins(c, d)
```

Comment: Works for me, can't reproduce. And this should be the case - the print can't affect that code. Perhaps you are not waiting long enough to see the final output, or it is being lost in a sea of "recusion" lines?

Comment: thanks. It turns out I wasn't waiting long enough.

Comment: If you think about the problem you are trying to solve you should be able to come up with a much better solution that only needs a fraction of the recursive calls.

Comment: @Duncan Yes now I am working on dynamic program. But wanted to make a recursive program first. But even this recursive program is incorrent as for coins = [5,25] change = 56 it is showing 4 coins.

Comment: Recursive is fine (my first attempt is 2395 recursive calls for your original problem). Hint: remember all the results you've calculated so far and then a new value is either a single coin or the minimum of all the ways of combining two smaller amounts.

Comment: @Duncan This program is giving wrong output for these cases. Any hint? coins = [3,10] change = 12, change = 15

Comment: You forgot to account for the cases where it is impossible to make change. So `coins=[3,10], change=12` will try the 10 plus `min_coins([3,10],2)` which (from the `mincoins=change` line) returns 2 even though there is no way to make 2 from the available coins.

Answer (score 6):

Consoles are quite slow, and you weren't patient enough:

```
python your_program.py | wc -l
684886
```

There are better ways, use a global counter variable or return a pair of `(mincoins, counter)`.

Comment: Okay thanks for clarifying. But when I ran the code without print statement the output came in less than 2 seconds. But when I added print it's running for much more time. Why is it so?

Comment: @ailhahc because Python can do 684886 recursive calls in under 2 seconds but not when it has to write the output to the console as well. `print` is slow!

Comment: It might be worth printing a dynamic variable when debugging, perhaps printing coins and change at each recursion to see the state of your program.

Comment: @Duncan: nope. On my computer, `print` only doubles the execution time (when output is redirected). As I said, consoles are notoriously slow.